# Narrowing search result to multiple categories

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to narrow down search results to be within any given categories.
My search body that works on elasticsearch 2.2.0

```
{
   "filter":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "categories":"16310211"
               }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                  "categories":"493964"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":25,
   "from":0
}
```

However now we are using AWS hosted services and they only provide support for 1.5.6. When I run the same code I get back a http 400 bad request. How can I achieve the same effect of filtering results by multiple criteria (one or more) on 1.5.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're committed to using multiple `match` queries, then you will need to combine them with a `bool` **query**. Try this:

```
{
   "query":{        <--- use query here instead of filter
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "categories":"16310211"
               }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                  "categories":"493964"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":25,
   "from":0
}
```

However, generally the `match` query is used for doing full text searching. It looks as if your "categories" are exact values. I would recommend a `term` filter for this type of data instead. You may have a better experience with the following:

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "bool":{
          "should":[
            { "term":{"categories":"16310211"} },
            { "term":{"categories":"493964"} }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size":25,
  "from":0
}
```