# failed to parse search source, expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

My Search Body:

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "should":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "categories":2
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "categories":5                         
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "name":"perferendis"
               }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                  "brand":"in"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "filter":{
      "and":{
         "filters":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":{
                     "term":{
                        "condition":1
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "highest_sales_rank":{
                     "gte":96
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "review_rating":{
                     "gte":1
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "review_count":{
                     "gte":12
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "upper_price":{
                     "gte":68
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":{
                     "term":{
                        "updated_at":0
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":{
      "updated_at":"asc"
   },
   "size":10,
   "from":40
}
```

However if I take out the filtered part the query succeeds

```
"filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "should":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "categories":2
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "categories":5                         
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
```

I previously used this format:

```
"filter":{
  "bool":{
     "should":[
        {
           "match":{
              "categories":"16310211"
           }
        },
        {
           "match":{
              "categories":"493964"
           }
        }
     ]
  }
},
```

but it only works with elastic search 2, and as AWS only supports 1.5.6 I am not able to  use this format, related to my previous question [Narrowing search result to multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664220/narrowing-search-result-to-multiple-categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Query DSL had changes among version 1.x and 2.x, do you need change your query, i did an example.

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "categories": 2
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "categories": 5
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "bool": {
                        "should": [
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "name": "perferendis"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match": {
                                 "brand": "in"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "must": [
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "highest_sales_rank": {
                           "gte": 96
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "review_rating": {
                           "gte": 1
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "review_count": {
                           "gte": 12
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "upper_price": {
                           "gte": 68
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "must_not": [
                  {
                      "term": {
                        "condition":1
                      }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "updated_at":0
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort":{
      "updated_at":"asc"
   },
   "size":10,
   "from":40
}
```

And i removed your AND filter, AND filters does not cache in a good way.
Feel free to ask some questions.